# How can I assign a number to each group and a total number of groups on the dataset to display

Tags: reporting-services, count, ssrs-grouping

I have a dataset that is grouped by the CustomerId with multiple row information for each CustomerId.

I'm trying to create a numbering for each group (customerId) that gets created sequentially and then a total of groups.

So basically I am looking for the report to calculate that there will 5 groups here and then go 1 of 3, 2 of 3, 3 of 3 on the group header row (so I'm assigning a number of each CustomerId and seeing how many are on that Company)....

I have used the page breaks in the past for this but not possible this time around because I cannot break the pages.  I have tried using RunningValue but not working so I'm lost here.

```
Header    |  Customer A     1 of 3
Details

Header    |  Customer B     2 of 3
Details

Header    |  Customer C     3 of 3
Details
```

Answer (score 0):

Say I have data like this:

[image]

And a simple table with a Group based on `Customer`:

[image]

The expression I'm using in the group header row is:

```
="Customer " & Fields!Customer.Value & " ("
  & RunningValue(Fields!Customer.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing)
    & " of "
    & CountDistinct(Fields!Customer.Value, "DataSet1") & ")"
```

Which is using a couple of aggregate functions and using these to create a longer string with the Customer detail.

You can see that using `CountDistinct` is the key here - it's used in `RunningValue` to get the group ranking and also as an aggregate expression by itself to get the total in the Dataset (where `DataSet1` is the Dataset name).

Results look good:

[image]

You will of course need to tweak slightly for your field names and your exact formatting requirements.